# How can I write an 'if' statement so blank spaces in an input field are not allowed?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, and having a hard time trying to write a conditional statement where if an input field is empty/blank, or contains any other character besides a-z, an error is given.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input#first, #city, #subject, input#last, textarea#message').on("keyup bind cut copy paste", function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var first = new RegExp('[a-z]');
  if (/^\s*$/.test(first.value));
  if(value=='' || first.length<=1) {
  if(value=='' || last.length<=1);
  if(value=='' || city.length<=1);
  if (first.test(value));
    $(this).css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
    $(this).css('background-color','#ffcece');
  }
  else {
   $(this).css('border','1px solid #ffd09d');
   $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Would you want to just use HTML5 form validation? It won't work on some old browsers, but you'll save yourself a lot of headache.

Comment: I'd rather use the javascript, so I can try and learn it.

Comment: Do you have the error message?

Comment: So look for spaces. Pick one: [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: Your code cant work with the last.length and all that, your conditions are wrong. You dont declare last and city anywhere.

Comment: As for HTML5, although it is great, know that 18% of browsers do not fully support it. That's almost 1 customer out of 5 that may not load your page properly and go to a competitor and that's bad for business. So when possible, you should consider avoiding it when it comes to validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input#first, #city, #subject, input#last, textarea#message').on("keyup bind cut copy paste",   
function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  var first = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+$');
  if (first.test(value)) {
      $(this).css('border','2px solid #ff0000');
      $(this).css('background-color','#ffcece');
  }
  else {
      $(this).css('border','1px solid #ffd09d');
      $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: Maybe it should be a-zA-Z (or a case insentive flag)?

Comment: That's an excellent point, I was just copying the OP regex, but you're right that was probably a mistake. I've made the change.

Comment: Thanks Marlon, I had a ; at the end of the if statement instead of a {. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This:

```
document.getElementById("yourInputPanel").addEventListener("onchange",function(){

    if(document.getElementById("yourInputPanel").search(" ") > -1){
    ...
    Handling Code
    ...
    }

});
```